# How to add Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider to SQL server for linkedserver

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, oledb

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

I donwloaded Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 from this link. Or Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 also downloaded.

But I can't see the list of OLE Provider on mu SQL Server with **exec sp_enum_oledb_providers** stored procedure.

What can I do about this ? How can I add the provider to my SQL Server ?